# Yii CMenu Item doesnt get class active

Tags: php, yii

Format looks like:

```
array(
   array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('site/index')),
   array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page')),
   array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
```

)

But if I am clicking on an item, it doesnt get the class active.
I am using the urlmanager and url paths.
I still dont know whats going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can see answers from this thread - [CMenu - active class not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622672/cmenu-active-class-not-rendering).
They explain how to use active param for menu items.